# How do I increase the timeout for a docker in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Once in a few Jenkins pipeline runs I get the error: `Getting ERROR: Timeout after 1 minutes` in a step that uses `docker.image(docker_image_here)` from the docker-pipeline plugin, how can I increase the timeout for this step?

I tried to add `timeout(10)` before the step and add `sleep(time:60,unit:"SECONDS")` after the step both solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this with that plugin is to run your Jenkins distro with a set of custom java args that would set the timeout. As per: [this PR](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/commit/8c18b064335c3aafff770aa19f2e40c117c910c5) and [this comment](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42322?focusedCommentId=303679&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-303679) you need to add:

`-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.CLIENT_TIMEOUT=250`

Depending on your full use-case I might recommend using something case as it seems that this plugin is no longer supported/up for adoption and in terms of configurability for stuff like timeout there doesn't seem to be an interest in implementing it. (Judging by the github Issues raised on the subject and how they were handled)

Comment: what docker pipeline Jenkins plug-in do you recommend with timeout configurations?

Comment: It kind of depends on your use case (whether you are building or just running) and where does this happen. (static VM, container, Kubernetes cluster, etc)

Comment: I'm running tests on a docker which runs on an EC2 instance.

Comment: If the issue occurs when pulling a new image there should be a "pull timeout" option within your "cloud config" -> "Docker agent Templates".